# How to find the max number in shell

Tags: shell

In my project, I want to find the max number with shell.

here is my shell code:

```
jobnuminit=0

for i in $(cat jobidtmp)
do
  jobnum=`bjobs -l $i | grep Start| awk '{print $8}'`
  echo $jobnum
  if [ $jobnum -gt $jobnuminit ]
  then
     jobnuminit=$jobnum
  fi
done

echo $jobnuminit
```

And the value of jobnum should be:

```
144
144
8
8
12 
8
8
8
8
8
8
12
8
8
8
8
12
12
20
12
12
8
8
```

And the value of jobnuminit should be 144, but the result is 8.
I have tried:

```
if [ $jobnum > $jobnuminit ]
```

But it failed again, Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use just sort:

```
sort -n file | tail -1
```

Comment: I don't want to stor jobnum to a file.